# While loop causing lag for SDL_Rect and SDL_Textures?

Tags: c++, rendering, sdl, lag, rect

I'm making a game using C++ and SDL, the game is a Space Invaders type of game. It's all been going smoothly until I added a background image in the while loop, this is the render and init code for the background:

**SZ_Background.cpp:**

```
void SZ_Background::Init(SDL_Renderer* pRenderer)
{
    int w, h;

    SDL_GetRendererOutputSize(pRenderer, &w, &h);

    bg_img.x = 0;
    bg_img.y = 0;
    bg_img.h = h;
    bg_img.w = w;

    SDL_Surface* background_img = IMG_Load("content/bg_img.bmp");
    SDL_Texture* background_img_tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(pRenderer, background_img);

    SDL_RenderCopy(pRenderer, background_img_tex, NULL, &bg_img);
}

void SZ_Background::Render(SDL_Renderer* pRenderer)
{
    int w, h;

    SDL_GetRendererOutputSize(pRenderer, &w, &h);

    bg_img.x = 0;
    bg_img.y = 0;
    bg_img.h = h;
    bg_img.w = w;

    SDL_Surface* background_img = IMG_Load("content/bg_img.bmp");
    SDL_Texture* background_img_tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(pRenderer, background_img);

    SDL_RenderCopy(pRenderer, background_img_tex, NULL, &bg_img);
}
```

**main.cpp - The loop:**

```
if (GameState == 3)
    {
        printf("INFO: Game State: %d - Game Screen Loaded\n", GameState);
        mainEnemies.gameover = false;
        mainBG.Init(game_renderer);
        gOver.Init(game_renderer);
        while (!done)
        {
            aTimer.resetTicksTimer();

            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(game_renderer, 0, 0, 20, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
            SDL_RenderClear(game_renderer);

            mainBG.Render(game_renderer);

            gOver.Update(game_renderer);
            gOver.Input();
            gOver.Render(game_renderer);

            SDL_RenderPresent(game_renderer);

            if (gOver.rMenu == true)
            {
                SDL_RenderClear(game_renderer);
                SDL_RenderPresent(game_renderer);
                GameState = 0;
                break;
            }

            if (aTimer.getTicks() < DELTA_TIME)
            {
                SDL_Delay(DELTA_TIME - aTimer.getTicks());
            }
        }
    }
```

mainBG is the background.

Comment: Awesome, removing them from the Render worked like a charm, thank you so much! So annoying I didn't try that.

Comment: @Blaze you should move your comment to an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: @BradAllred good idea, it's an answer now. I originally posted it as a comment because I was not sure if that solved the problem that OP was having.

Comment: Did you really not question why `Init` and `Render` are identical? Also, you should probably use smart pointers, but that's another story.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're initializing `background_img` and `background_img_tex` every time you call `SZ_Background::Render`:

```
SDL_Surface* background_img = IMG_Load("content/bg_img.bmp");
SDL_Texture* background_img_tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(pRenderer,background_img);
```

That's not necessary, you already initialize them in `SZ_Background::Init`, and that's all you need to do. The way it is now, not only might it slow down the program by loading that background from disk every frame, but it's also leaking memory every time (mostly your RAM for `SDL_Surface`, and your GPU's memory for SDL_Texture). Remove those `IMG_Load` and `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface` calls in `Render` and it should be better.